# Which config file was loaded?

Tags: java, spring-boot

My Spring application uses multiple config files:

```
spring.config.name = default,local,application,dev
```

So we can use the config files default.yml, local,yml, application,yml and dev.yml

The local.yml is the config file the end user should use for configuration.

But how can I check in the Java code if the local.yml was loaded?

Comment: the corresponding config file is selected by the active profile, right?

Comment: No. Spring Boot loads these config files one after the other. All of these config files are loaded. We don't use profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another answer I've found a hint. This is what works:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

/**
 * Checks if the local.yml was loaded.
 *
 * @return true if the local.yml was laoded
 */
public boolean isLocalAppConfigLoaded() {
    MutablePropertySources propertySources = ((AbstractEnvironment)environment).getPropertySources();
    return StreamSupport.stream(propertySources.spliterator(), false)
        .filter(propertySource -> propertySource instanceof EnumerablePropertySource)
        .map(PropertySource::getName)
        .anyMatch(sourceName -> sourceName.matches("^applicationConfig: \\[.*?local.yml]$"));
}
```

This gets all `PropertySources` laoded in this Spring context. Every source has a name and the files have a name with the format "applicationConfig: []". So I'm searching for my config file there.